# How to configure `I18n Ally` VsCode plugin to read nested locales from multiple locale files?

Tags: i18next, react-i18next, i18n-ally

I have few language folders with locale files inside

```
  locales         
  ├── en
  |   ├── common.json
  |   ├── ...
  |   └── article.json
  └── de
      ├── common.json
      ├── ...
      └── article.json
```

And i have a nested structure of locale.json like this

```
{
  "title": "Something",
  "menu": {
    "first": "First",
    "second": "Second",
    "third": "Third"
  }
}
```

I can't configure the extension settings to read this locales structure

Comment: Did you find out a solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was struggling to make this work too, then finally found out the right config.

Important thing is to set **localesPaths** as well as **pathMatcher** in settings accordingly.

```
"i18n-ally.localesPaths": "src/locales",
"i18n-ally.namespace": true,
"i18n-ally.pathMatcher": "{locale}/{namespace}.json",
```

Also, developers notice in docs that it is important to set `namespace` to true **before** `pathMatcher`.